# software raid priority (systemtap)

Tags: raid, priority

I'd like to know on which priority software raid works (level 1 if it matters). So I wrote simple systemtap script to do the job, but I'm not sure if I have done it correctly.

```
[root@asus-ux21e ~]# cat raid.stp 
probe module("raid1").function("*") {
    printf( "name: %s | prio: %d | nice: %d\n", task_execname(task_current()), task_prio(task_current()), task_nice(task_current()));
}
```

Could anyone review it, and tell me on which priority software raid works?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense. You're looking at functions from a particular module, but the location of a function doesn't determine its priority. What determines the priority is the priority of the thread that calls the function.

The kernel runs one kernel thread per RAID-1 volume, with a name like `md0_raid1` (`ps` shows it in brackets, e.g. `[md0_raid1]`, to indicate that this is a kernel thread rather than a thread executing code from a file). You can see its priority with `ps`:

```
ps -o pid,pri,comm -C md0_raid1
  PID PRI COMMAND
  263  19 md0_raid1
```

Comment: So how can I get the same functionality from SystemTap? The question is more about how to do it in SystemTap, then using ps. But thank you.